# how to find a next word from a 'dataset' using ngram with a given test set.

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

**given a corpus and test set.**
corpus contains 10000 complete sentences. 
The test set contains 100 incomplete sentence,where each sentence has 3 consecutive words.
I want to train the corpus using ngrams and predict the next word for the Test Set.

```
text = 'dataset.txt'
# Order of the grams
n = 2


ngrams = {}


words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
for i in range(len(words)-n):
    gram = ' '.join(words[i:i+n])
    if gram not in ngrams.keys():
        ngrams[gram] = []
    ngrams[gram].append(words[i+n])


currentGram = ' '.join(words[0:n])
result = currentGram
for i in range(30):
    if currentGram not in ngrams.keys():
        break
    possibilities = ngrams[currentGram]
    nextItem = possibilities[random.randrange(len(possibilities))]
    result += ' '+nextItem
    rWords = nltk.word_tokenize(result)
    currentGram = ' '.join(rWords[len(rWords)-n:len(rWords)])
```

---

test set is in .csv format
[Top five lines of a test set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPTUN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are asking for an algorithm suited for this task.

You could predict sequences using [Markov Models](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/ijprai.pdf).

Depending on how much data you have, you should consider [RNNs](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/nlp-sequence-models/recurrent-neural-network-model-ftkzt), [LSTMs](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/nlp-sequence-models/long-short-term-memory-lstm-KXoay) and [GRUs](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/nlp-sequence-models/gated-recurrent-unit-gru-agZiL).